# REST POST service : special characters in post data is converted

Tags: rest, http-post

I am invoking a REST POST service to which I am sending the following JSON body,

```
[{"studentId":99999}]
```

But, the data which is received by server is,

```
%5B%7B%22studenId%22%3A99999%7D%5D
```

and getting errored out. Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: How do you send the data and do you set correct encoding along with content-type?

Comment: Content-Type 
application/json;charset=utf-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your content is url encoded. Did you send your content using an HTML form (you shouldn't)? If you're in a browser, you should leverage AJAX to do this:

- With JQuery: `$.post` (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

  ```
  $.post( "/someaddr", [{"studentId":99999}])
            .done(function(data) {
    (...)
  });
  ```
- With Angular: `$http.post` (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

  ```
  $http.post('/someaddr', [{"studentId":99999}])
            .success(function(data, status, headers) {
    (...)
  });
  ```

It would be really helpful if you give us more details about the way you used to send your data.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry